# Parameter argument not working right (beginner)

Tags: python

Newb question, when I write:

```
def right_indent(s):
    print ' '*70+'s'       #puts argument after 70 spaces
right_indent('michael')
                                                                     s
```

Why does it return s as a result? Shouldn't it be michael?
This seems really simple but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Keep in mind 'print' and 'return' are two different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the name of the variable: `s`

This is what you put instead: `'s'`

A value enclosed in quotes is a string literal.

Answer (score 2):

There are quote marks around `s`, so it treats it as a literal string instead of as a variable name. Try:

```
print ' '*70+s
```

You might be familiar with PHP, which happily translates variable names even if they're inside quotes. Python doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

All of the previous answers are correct.  I just thought that it might be important to mention that your function *returns* `None` (since it has no `return ...` statement).  (try:

```
A=right_indent('michael')
print A   #Prints 'None'
```